# Angular JS render variable in scope function to view and make comparison

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hi I have been using this tag to change my css  style, if the condition totalAsset and sortedAsset are same

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="x in myData" ng-click="sort()" 
ng-class="{'lightblue': x.totalAsset == sortedAsset}">
```

totalAsset is my data in like this

```
$scope.myData = [
{
totalAsset: "23557"
},
{
totalAsset: "4512190",   
},
{
totalAsset: "2190",   
},
{
totalAsset: "1256790",   
}
]
```

i have create a function that self sort the totalAsset

```
$scope.sort = function (){
$scope.unsortedAsset = $scope.myData.totalAsset;
$scope.sortedAsset=$scope.unsortedAsset.split("").sort().join("");
}
```

in the logic only the first and last row will become blue the other two rows remain same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `sort()` you directly access `$scope.myData.totalAsset`. This gets resolved as a reference to the last object in `$scope.myData` that has a `totalAsset` member.

Instead you wanted to iterate over all objects in `myData`.  That can be achieved by supplying a parameter to the `sort` function like in the code below.

```
$scope.sort = function (totalAsset){
    $scope.unsortedAsset = totalAsset;
    $scope.sortedAsset=$scope.unsortedAsset.split("").sort().join("");
}
```

Then you also must call the `sort` function by supplying the parameter value.

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="x in myData" ng-click="sort(x.totalAsset)" ng-class="{'lightblue': x.totalAsset == sortedAsset}">
```

Comment: Thank you, I still have a bug in my code, that is there are many result in my data but ng-click only give a true/false when i click on the certain item. How can I use ng-click to click one time on my table to display all the true table rows?

Comment: Actually that´s a quite different question. I suggest you ask that as a new SO question.